# SAP UI5 : How to clear the input fields after submit

Tags: javascript, sapui5

after providing login credentials when i click login button it takes me to next screen But the values remain there when i press log out i am routed to login screen where it holds user name and password which provided by me during login

pls help me out to resolve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset controls to their initial values in SAPUI5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439991/how-to-reset-controls-to-their-initial-values-in-sapui5)

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the Input value via.

```
this.oLabelInput.setValue("");
```

And do this in the onRouteMatched() or onPatternMatched() of your Login page. Then you will always get empty fields